# Initialize database from dump inside docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to deploy a web application using Docker and docker-compose. To start with, I'm just focusing on the interaction between the PostgreSQL database and the Spring back-end. By following some tutorials I ended up with the following docker-compose.

```
version: "3"
services:
 app:
  image: 'first-docker-image:latest'
  build:
   context: ./backend
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: app
  depends_on:
    - dbpostgresql
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
 dbpostgresql:
  image: postgres:12.9
  container_name: dbpostgresql
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=appuser
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
   - POSTGRES_DB=app_db
  ports:
   - 5432:5432
```

The Dockerfile inside the backend directory calls the jar for to start my Spring back-end, and works fine. Also, a connection is made to the database 'app_db'.

The only problem that remains is the fact that this database is empty, so all API calls result in errors, as there are no tables or data in the database. I do however have an PostgreSQL dump (app_dump.bak) that I want to use to initialize this database.

To fix my problem, I can run the docker-compose and after the containers are up, I copy the data dump into the container like this.

```
sudo docker cp app_dump.bak <DOCKER_ID>:/app_dump.bak
```

After this I can create a shell inside the container and restore the dump by doing

```
pg_restore --no-owner --no-privileges -d app_db -U appuser app_dump.bak
```

And after doing this, everything works. I can make API calls to the back-end and the corresponding results are shown.

I'm looking for a way to do this procedure (initializing the database) when running docker-compose, so no extra steps are needed after the containers are up. Is there any way to specify this behavior inside the docker-compose set-up?

I'm quite new to Docker, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an init container which will mount your file and run the command;

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: "first-docker-image:latest"
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - dbpostgresql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  dbpostgresql:
    image: postgres:12.9
    container_name: dbpostgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=appuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=app_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  dbpostgresql_init:
    image: postgres:12.9
    container_name: dbpostgresql_init
    command: pg_restore -h dbpostgresql --no-owner --no-privileges -d app_db -U appuser app_dump.bak
    volumes:
      - ./app_dump.bak:/app_dump.bak
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=appuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=app_db
    depends_on:
      dbpostgresql:
        condition: service_started
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble with a permission error when the `dbpostgresql_init` service tries to connect to `dbpostgresql`, try setting the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` to `trust` like this:

```yaml
  dbpostgresql:
    image: postgres:12.9
    container_name: dbpostgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=appuser
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_DB=app_db
```

According to the [image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` is not used in that case.

Take into consideration that this is insecure. For the moment I couldn't manage to find a way to pass the required password in the `pg_restore` command (without requiring user input).

A possibility could be to provide a custom [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html#AUTH-PG-HBA-CONF) file to allow connections from the `dbpostgresql_init` service.